# Which UI item allows dynamic expansion on the go in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Suppose I have a single **text box** and a **radio button** placed below the **text box** .

What I want is that **if** the user enters some text and **ALSO** clicks the radio button a similar **text box** and a **radio button** should appear just below. And similar thing should happen if the user does that for new UI items.

Any suggestions what classes I should be looking for?

Comment: You could add a hidden control to your ui using signals and slots to make it visible. I have done that in a few cases.

Comment: [Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)?

Comment: This will only be done once or if you type something in the new textbox and press the new button should appear new?

Comment: @drescherjm If possible, can you be more specific, I mean name of Classes I should be looking for, Or is it just Signals and slots that will do the needfull and the property hidden?

Comment: QWidget::setVisible(bool) is the slot to connect to your signal.

Comment: Do you want to put visible widgets that exist or do you want to create new widgets?

Comment: Stop looking for specific classes and just implement the logic you want. There's nothing "pre-made" that does 100% what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant class you need to handle the inserting of new widgets is one of the `QLayout` subclasses, most likely `QVBoxLayout` it sounds like. This will allow you to insert a new textbox and radio button at the bottom of the layout, which will then automatically expand to fit these new widgets.

Inserting the new objects is pretty straightforward. Connect a slot to a signal of the `QRadioButton` that's at the bottom of the layout, like the `QRadioButton::toggled` or `QRadioButton::clicked` signals. This slot will check if the above textbox has any text in it, and, if so, insert a new textbox/radio button pair below them.

To be clear, this slot should be a method of the widget that uses the layout to arrange its sub-widgets. For example, if you're putting all these objects in a `QGroupBox`, then that's the object to which you'd add the slot I'm describing.

Here is an (untested) example:

```
class Group : public QGroupBox {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Group(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QGroupBox(parent)
        {
            layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
            insertNewRow();
        }

    private slots:
        void insertNewRow(bool checked = true) {
            /* You might want to make this remove the row if the button is unchecked */
            if (!checked) 
                return;

            /* Only add row if text box is non-empty */
            if (textBoxes.isEmpty() || textBoxes.last()->text().isEmpty())
                return;

            /* Disconnect slot for previous radio button */
            QObject::disconnect(radioButtons.last(), 0, 0, 0);

            /* Add new text box and button, labeled Button 1, Button 2, etc. */
            textBoxes.append(new QLineEdit("", this));
            radioButtons.append(new QRadioButton(QString("Button %1").arg(textBoxes.size())), this));

            /* Connect signal/slot to add new row when clicked */
            QObject::connect(radioButtons.last(), &QRadioButton::toggled, this, &Group::insertNewRow);
        }

    private:
        QVBoxLayout* layout;
        QList<QLineEdit*> textBoxes;
        QList<QRadioButton*> radioButtons;
};
```